# How do I get video stats using youtube v3 api in PHP

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This is one of the most simple questions, but I cannot find the answer anywhere from the docs to forums. I want to use php to get videos stats such as like count. I do not want to do this using cURL, I want to do it using the SDK and OOP.

I cannot find anywhere how I am meant to structure requests as such using php .for example I have used

```
  $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
        'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
        'maxResults' => 50

      ));
```

to get playlist items, but not enough video info is returned. I cannot do

```
$youtube->videos->listVideos
```

Please help me.

Comment: Hi, haven't use youtube-api , but a quick look into their documentation tell me you can do something like this link to achieve what you want [video api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) . You can pick php tab for php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) Returns a collection of playlist items that match the API request parameters.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    playlistItem Resource
  ]
}
```

Each  [playlistItem Resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems#resource) contains information about the playlist item.

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "playlistId": string,
    "position": unsigned integer,
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": string,
      "videoId": string,
    }
  },
  "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": string,
    "startAt": string,
    "endAt": string,
    "note": string,
    "videoPublishedAt": datetime
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": string
  }
}
```

Which includes a videoId which can be used to run [Videos: getRating](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating) Retrieves the ratings that the authorized user gave to a list of specified videos.

```
function videosGetRating($service, $id, $params) {
    $params = array_filter($params);
    $response = $service->videos->getRating(
        $id,
        $params
    );

    print_r($response);
}

videosGetRating($service,
    'Ks-_Mh1QhMc,c0KYU2j0TM4,eIho2S0ZahI', 
    array('onBehalfOfContentOwner' => ''));
```